# Set MFC dialog inside a cview

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a cdialog in mfc and I want to host it in a cview so when you click on another cview, it will come to the top, unlike a normal dialog. 
I tried by setting the cview as parent of the dialog, but the dialog did not showup. Is there a way to do this?
Thnaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `CFormView`. A `CFormView` is based on a dialog template, so it's basically a view that looks/acts/works like a dialog (and unless you've done something strange, your existing dialog template should work fine for the `CFormView` as well).

Comment: Thanks Jerry. I created a class from CForm view resource. How do I display it in a modeles way, like a modeless dialog? I searched but did not find the exact syntax.

Comment: @gishu: the "modeless" happens automatically -- as far as mode goes, it's just a view like any other view, so it's created when the user creates a view, and remains until the user closes the view (or window hosting the view).